# Hong-Ou-Mandel (HOM) effect and symmetric beam splitter

Tags: optics, quantum-entanglement, interference, quantum-optics

When modelling the photons' behaviour in [Hong-Ou-Mandel (HOM) effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hong%E2%80%93Ou%E2%80%93Mandel_effect), those reaching the beam-splitter from the bottom side are considered to act differently than those coming from the other one:

> In addition, reflection off the bottom side of the beam splitter
>   introduces a relative phase shift of −1 in the associated term in the
>   superposition.
>
> [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hong%E2%80%93Ou%E2%80%93Mandel_effect)

Is there an easy way to explain that if the beam splitter is **symmetric**?

---

**Edit.**  When the two photons reach the beam splitter, in the HOM (Hong-Ou-Mandel) effect, one would think that four different things could happen:

- Both get the same direction and it is the right one
- Both get the same direction and it is the top one
- Each one gets in a different direction (*2)

The fact is that the two terms "Each one gets in a different direction" get compensated because one gets a positive constant and the other one a negative one. My question is about that fact, that is justified because of the reflection off the bottom side in one of this two situations.

Comment: Are you familiar with the behavior of ordinary waves at a fixed boundary? This is the same type of situation.

Comment: @probably_someone, what do you mean? I am familiar with it but I do not find the analogy.

Comment: Reflection of a transverse wave from a fixed boundary introduces a phase shift of 180 degrees. The waves reflecting off of the beam splitter acquire an analogous phase shift of -1. Meanwhile, in the limit of a perfectly thin beam splitter, the waves transmitted through the beam splitter acquire no phase shift.

Comment: @probably_someone, I have edited my question because I think I was not explaining myself well.

Comment: Symmetric is not a factor. It's for convenience. An asymmetric beamsplitter introduces an overall phase shift but demonstrates the same effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why the one term gets a minus sign compared to the other, has to do with the fact that in quantum mechanics beamsplitters is represented by a unitary operator (matrix). If one wants to do that without making the elements of the matrix complex, then one side must get a minus sign while the other side doesn't:
$$ a \rightarrow (a+b)/\sqrt{2} $$
$$ b \rightarrow (b-a)/\sqrt{2} $$
Of course, there is no reason why one cannot have complex entries in the matrix. It would just represent a phase. This allows one to write the transformation in a symmetric way:
$$ a \rightarrow (a+ib)/\sqrt{2} $$
$$ b \rightarrow (b+ia)/\sqrt{2} $$
It turns out that both these ways of writing down the transformation through the beam splitter give the same result: HOM interference.

Comment: The matrix of a beamsplitter in the classical wave theory also unitary and has the 180 degree phase difference. Otherwise, energy won't be conserved. There are no such things as "quantum mechanics beamsplitters."